# External JS file's functions not loading after infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr, infinite-scroll

I am using gumroad.js on tumblr with infinite scroll

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gumroad.com/js/gumroad.js"></script>
```

This creates an overlay checkout (modal) window on button clicks. For the first 15 posts it loads fine. But once the remaining buttons load on infinite scroll, they do not load with the js functionality.

The script is located in the page's `<head>`

Do I need to reload the file in every callback of the infinite scroll?: `function(newElements) {`

EDIT

I just noticed that the soundcloud player is also disappearing after infinite scroll. These are both custom classes. They show up in the inspector as having the classes still in tact, but the js files are not getting processed.

Comment: AFAIK, you would need to call the javascript each time you add new posts to the DOM.

Comment: so load the entire js file each time new content is populated? How do you do that in a callback?

Comment: Its an odd one. I looked at the docs, and couldn't find an append / update method, so I imagine you will have to call the JS file each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinite scroll has been known to cause problems with scripts. Yes, you'd probably need to reinitialize Gumroad in the callback after each page load. I don't know much about Gumroad, but a quick search turned up

`Gumroad.init()`

as a method to reinitialize the code.

Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but putting that line in the callback should work!

---

**EDIT:**

We can't prevent Gumroad.js from creating duplicate buttons after every run of the `init()`, so we'll just have to wipe all buttons and let them reinitialize. There's also no way to unattach the click handlers, and therefore you'll need to clone the anchors to remove them. After each infinite scroll callback, you'll want to run this code to set all gumroad links back to normal and then call `Gumroad.init()` to reinitialize. I am not sure if you're using jQuery, but if so, it's the simplest way.

Using [their demo](https://gumroad.com/overlay) as the model:

**jQuery**

```
$('.gumroad-button').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).clone().children().remove().end()); 
});
Gumroad.init();
```

**Vanilla javascript**

```
for (var i = 0, a = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i].className.indexOf("gumroad-button") > -1) {
    var clone = a[i].cloneNode();
    clone.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a[i].lastChild.nodeValue));
    a[i].parentNode.replaceChild(clone, a[i]);
  }
}
Gumroad.init();
```

---

**Notes**

<kbd>[`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/)</kbd> is needed to refer back to the cloned element after selecting the child elements for removal
<kbd>[`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)</kbd> doesn't remove text nodes so only the 'icon' part of the button will be removed after cloning (optimal).

If you're using the vanilla javascript, you'll need to copy the text node ("Buy my product") after cloning it. But instead of deep cloning (clone all child elements as well) using the DOM <kbd>[`Node.cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode)</kbd> method (by passing in `true` to `.cloneNode(true)` to clone the anchor and then remove the unnecessary child elements (i.e. the icon) like the jQuery way, you can just shallow clone the anchor only and then copy the text over.

Again, we need to clone and replace the anchor link element to get rid of the duplicate click handler, or else when you click on the button it will actually execute the Gumroad overlay modal twice.

Comment: That works! - for newly loaded content. Unfortunately it creates a duplicate of the existing (already loaded) content in 'function(newElements) {'

Comment: Also having the exact same issue with the soundcloud html5 player. Any suggestions there?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with the Gumroad service, but can you clarify what you mean by duplicate content? Do you mean it's creating two Gumroad buttons after each page is loaded?

Comment: Yes, it creates another button on top of the old one when a new page is loaded.